# Como contornar o problema de página expirada?

Tags: http, post

Meu problema é o seguinte:

O utilizador faz o login, os dados são enviados para a página de solicitações (que lista todas as solicitações da pessoa de forma resumida). Nessa página é verificado se é válido o login. Se for, é exibido o restante da página, se não for, volta para a página de login com mensagem de erro. Aí, na página de solicitações, a pessoa clica em um link para visualizar o conteúdo da solicitação.

Ao voltar para a página anterior (Solicitações), aparece a mensagem que foi expirada:

[image: Captura de Tela]

Ao pressionar <kbd>F5</kbd>, pede para reenviar:

[image: Captura de Tela]

## Pergunta

O que devo fazer para contornar isso?

Comment: Qual linguagem você está utilizando? Nos dê mais detalhes sobre a implementação :)

Comment: Não precisa de detalhes, o problema é puramente HTTP :)

Answer (score 10):

O navegador reclama de página expirada porque a página de solicitações é resultado de um `POST` (feito na página de login).

O certo é que, depois de você validar se o login da pessoa está correto, *redirecioná-la* para a página de solicitações. Isso resultará em um `GET` para essa página, então não haverá problema do usuário ter que resubmeter (o formulário de login, no caso) para listar novamentes as solicitações.

Comment: Ok, Acho que entendi! Vou tentar fazer isso!

Comment: Se der certo, não esqueça de dar a resposta como válida :)

Comment: Deu certo sim... muito obrigada!